# How to Generate a Flowchart from a Database or Spreadsheet on a Mac?

Tags: excel, filemaker, flowchart

Is there an easy, economical way to generate a flowchart from either a database (e.g., FileMaker Pro, or MS-Access) or a spreadsheet (e.g., Apple Numbers, or MS-Excel)?

What's being sought--on a Mac--is a way to create a database/spreadsheet table of flowchart nodes (with title/text, symbol type and linkage info)..."press a button"...and have a visually appealing flowchart generated.

Then...examine the result...update the table...re-generate...LTD.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post. First, you'll need OmniGraffle. Next, you'd need to convert the FileMaker data into OmniGraffle XML or use AppleScript. http://forums.omnigroup.com/showthread.php?t=1860